# Regrading Eigenvalues and Linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have $T:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $T((1,0))=(2,0)$ and $T((1,1))=(3,3)$.

It is clearly a linear map, but can I say immediately that $\lambda_1=2, ~ \lambda_2=3$ are eigenvalues of $T$?

How can I find $V_2$ and $V_3$?

Unfortunately this subject confuses me...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What makes you say it is clearly a linear map? *If* it's a linear map, then yes. To find the eigenspaces, use what you know about their dimensions and the eigenvectors you're given.

Comment: Actually the map is not "clearly linear". The map has not been properly defined yet, only the value at two individual vector have been fixed. But it turns out that _if we assume_ that $T$ is linear, then it is entirely determined by these two values. On the other hand there are plenty of non linear maps that agree with $T$ at these two vectors, but not elsewhere.

Comment: I say its clearly because there exists only one linear map such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for a basis $B=(v_1,...v_n)$

Comment: That only allows you to say that *if* $T$ is linear, then it's unique, as Marc van Leeuwen explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $\mathcal{B}=((1,0),(1,1))$, it is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $T$ be the linear map defined by $T((1,0)) = (2,0)$ and $T((1,1)) = (3,3)$

Knowing that,

$$T((1,0)) = (2,0) = 2 \cdot (1,0) \quad T((1,1)) = 3 \cdot (1,1)$$

If you write the matrix of $T$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ you get,

$$M = \mathrm{Mat}_{\mathcal{B}}(T) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} $$

Hence as $M$ is diagonal $T$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues can directly be read on the diagonal of $M$. So yes, the eigenvalues of $T$ are $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for that!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.